# How to remove specific part of localstorage value using removeitem?

Tags: local-storage

I have a local storage as follows

Key0 is key and its value is **{"fav1,fav2,fav3,fav4,fav5"}**

If i use localstorage.removeitem('key0'), whole value is completely removed

How do i specifically remove fav1 or fav2 or such using **removeitem** function or is there any simple way to remove a specific part of local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way of doing this since the value you store under a specific key is just a string. So, if you store `"fav1,fav2,fav3,fav4,fav5"` under the key `key0`, then this value is just a string like any other (e.g. `foobar`). If you want to change that string which is stored in localStorage, you have to 1) read it from localStorage, 2) change it manually, and then 3) store it back into localStorage under the same key.

The way this is usually done is by using JSON serialization and deserialization:

```
key = "key0";
value = JSON.stringify(["fav1", "fav2", "fav3", "fav4", "fav5"]);
// value is now the JSON string representing the array
localStorage.setItem(key, value);

newValue = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem(key))
// newValue is now an array with the values fav1, fav2, ... so we can manipulate it and store it back
newValue.pop();
newValue = JSON.stringify(newValue);
localStorage.setItem(key, newValue);
```